# NSObject call method on viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

Quite new to Objective-C so might be doing a few things wrong.
I am trying to call a method from an NSObject that is found on the viewcontroller here is my code.

**ViewController.h**

```
-(void)loadBarNavButtons;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Constants.h"
#import "Utils.h"
#import "DesignStyle.h"
#import "SocialConnection.h"

@implementation ViewController{
    SocialConnection *SC;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    // enables use of social connection
    SC = [[SocialConnection alloc] init];
    [SC setup:self]; // pass in the UIVIEWCONTROLLER - could not find another way to do this?
    // not sure if correct.

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

// method being called from NSObject
-(void)loadBarNavButtons{
  // DO Something here
}
```

**SocialConnection.m**

```
@implementation SocialConnection{
    UIView* view;
    UIViewController* controller;
}

// the setup function passes in a view controller
-(void)setup:(UIViewController*)UIController{
    controller = UIController;
    view = controller.view;
}

// setup when the user is logged in
//FIXME: This is the line that is broken
-(void)isLoggedIn{
    NSLog(@"Loggged in!");
    [controller loadBarNavButtons];
}
```

Giving me the following error:

> No Visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector
>   'loadBarNavButtons'

[image: Error Image]

I understand that it cannot find the method. 
Is it defined incorrectly in the .h file?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is an instance of `UIViewController`. You probably want it to be an instance of `ViewController`.

By the way: You should try to be more verbose with you names.